# My Blog Posts disappear everytime I make migrations. Heroku-Django blog

Tags: python, django, heroku

So I made a blog with django and hosted it on heroku(Free version), and every time I make new migrations, the posts that I uploaded earlier would disappear and left are the trial posts which I uploaded on my machine for testing. I don't understand why this is happening.

These are the commands I used.

`heroku run python manage.py makemigrations`
and then
`heroku run python manae.py migrate`

I don't think that it is any of the code that is throwing this problem. But if you need to check any of the files, I'll attach'em . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that you are still using SQLite, which is stored on disk. Django apps start off with SQLite by default, so if you haven't consciously changed your database that's certainly what you're using. Heroku's active storage is ["ephemeral"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku), meaning it goes away when you restart your dynos. This means that while your database will still look the same (because you haven't changed your models or migration files, after all), there won't be any data in it except stuff added after the dyno restarts.

The solution is to use a different database, such as PostGreSQL, that has its own server and lives independent of your Heroku dynos. You can learn more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/heroku-postgres).